# How can I deserialize an XML snippet to configure an already existing object?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

Here's my scenario, I've got the following class, and I want to have the constructor deserialize some elements of the class.  I would really rather NOT use a factory method here.

```
public abstract class AccessLevelAgentBase : IAccessLevelAgent
{
    public List<AccessLevel> AccessLevels { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string PasswordPrompt { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string GetAccessLevelKeystroke { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public int Doohicky { get; set;}

    public AccessLevelAgentBase(XElement agentElement)
    {
        // Some Mojo Here to take agentElement and serialize
        // from the XML below to set the values of PasswordPrompt,
        // GetAccessLevelKeystroke, and Doohicky.
    }
}
```

The XML:

```
<AccessLevelAgent>
    <PasswordPrompt> Password ?: </PasswordPrompt>
    <PromptCommand>Ctrl+X</PromptCommand>
    <Doohicky>50</Doohicky>
</AccessLevelAgent>
```

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from getting the completely serialized object in the first place?

Comment: there are needs to "re-evaluate" the serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple way...

```
public AccessLevelAgentBase(XElement agentElement)     
{
    this.AccessLevels  = (string)agentElement.Element("AccessLevels");
    this.GetAccessLevelKeystroke = (string)agentElement.Element("GetAccessLevelKeystroke");
    this.Doohicky = (int)agentElement.Element("Doohicky");
}
```

... not so simple way...

```
public AccessLevelAgentBase(XElement agentElement)
{
    var type = this.GetType();
    var props = from prop in type.GetProperties()
                let attrib = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlElementAttribute), true)
                                    .OfType<XmlElementAttribute>()
                                    .FirstOrDefault()
                where attrib != null
                let elementName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attrib.ElementName) 
                                            ? prop.Name 
                                            : attrib.ElementName
                let value = agentElement.Element(elementName)
                where value != null
                select new
                {
                    Property = prop,
                    Element = value,
                };

    foreach (var item in props)
    {
        var propType = item.Property.PropertyType;
        if (propType == typeof(string))
            item.Property.SetValue(this, (string)item.Element, null);
        else if (propType == typeof(int))
            item.Property.SetValue(this, (int)item.Element, null);
        else 
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: That IS the "simple" way, but I want it to generically look at the attributes on the class.

Comment: Then you will probably need to use reflection.

Comment: Was starting to get that impression, create a manual "helper" passing in the instance of the object, evaluating it, and then setting found XML Elements.

Comment: The `if/else` mess can be updated many ways... but I don't feel like applying the effort for an example.

Comment: FWIW There are 3rd party libaries available to help with these sort of tasks. e.g. Automapper

Comment: thanks for the post, I need to extend it for XmlArray and XmlAttribute, but that's fine.